# How to get this isPermaLink="false" text from guid?

Tags: java, rss, feed, rome

How to get this text isPermaLink="false" from guid?

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">article-67228311</guid>
```

I am using this library  **com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndEntry**. Is there a way to get value inside guid tag using this library? The below print statement prints the value as **article-67228311**, but I want to get **isPermaLink="false"** text.

**Sample code:**

```
try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createMinimal()) {
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(feedUrl);
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request); InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent()) {
        SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
        SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(stream));
        Iterator iter = feed.getEntries().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            SyndEntry syndEntry = (SyndEntry) iter.next();
            System.out.println("guid ========" + syndEntry.getUri());
        }
    }
}
```